# how can I check input integer number in multiple table C program?

Tags: c, scanf

I have C program about print multiple table when I have enter a integer number. And I also want to check integer number then notice error if I input wrong type, such as "1a" will show "wrong input! " or "-5" will show "The number enter must be greater than 0". Some one help me, please. Thank for reading! Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int n;
    printf ("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    check_input (n);
    multible (n);
}

int clean_stdin ()
{
    while (getchar () != 'n') {
    }
    return 1;
}

void check_input (int n)
{
    char c;
    do {
        printf ("Enter an integer: ");
    } while (((scanf ("%d%c", &n, &c) != 2 || c != 'n') && clean_stdin ()));

    printf ("done, number is %d", n);
    return 0;
}

int multible (int n)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        printf ("%d * %d = %d \n", n, i, n * i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me. In `check_input()` why you pass `n` if same `n` you are scanning there ?

Comment: For a start you need some forward declarations.

Comment: The compiler should be shouting warnings at you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is discombobulated to put it mildly. You check `c != 'n'` where you should check `c != '\n'`. `'n'` is ASCII char `110`, `'\n'` is the *newline* character (ASCII 10).

Next, your return type for `clean_stdin` should be `void` -- you return nothing, and your return type for `check_input` should be something that allows you to indicate success/failure of the check. You do not use `argc` or `argv`, so your declaration for `main()` should be `int main (void)`. You don't use any function declared in `stdlib.h`, so there is no need to include that header. None of your functions can be seen in `main()` because they are declared AFTER `main()` and there are no *function prototypes* specified ABOVE `main()`.

Let's look at how you can do what you are attempting to do. First, let's clean up `clean_stdin`, so it does what it is intended to do, e.g.

```
void clean_stdin ()
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

Next, if you use `scanf` (or any of that family of functions), you must check the **return** and handle the case where the user cancels input by generating a manual `EOF`, you must address the cases of *matching* or *input* failure (e.g. the return is less than the number of conversions specified), and finally, you identify and handle the good input case, using `clean_stdin` as intended to remove any characters that remain in `stdin`, so they don't bite you on your next call.

Since your intent is to get an integer input, there is no need to get it, then check it in a separate function, just create a function that fills an integer value (whose address is passed as a parameter) and returns a `1` to indicate *failure* or `0` to indicate *success*, e.g.

```
int get_int_input (int *n)
{
    *n = 0;

    for (;;) {
        int rtn, tmp;

        printf ("Enter an integer: ");

        rtn = scanf ("%d", &tmp);

        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* handle user canceled input */
            fputs ("(user canceled input).\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        if (rtn == 1) {     /* good input, set *n = tmp, clean, return */
            *n = tmp;
            clean_stdin();
            return 0;
        }
        /* handle matching or input failure */
        fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
        clean_stdin();
    }
}
```

Your `multible` function will work as is, but your loop limits are contrary to the limits normally seen, e.g. `i = 0; i < 10`, a tweak there:

```
int multible (int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf ("%d * %d = %d \n", n, i + 1, n * (i + 1));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then all that remains is getting the input needed and calling `multible`, e.g.

```
int main (void)
{
    int n;

    if (get_int_input (&n))
        return 1;

    multible (n);

    return 0;
}
```

Next, always compile with *warnings enabled*, and **do not** accept code until it *compiles cleanly without warning*. To enable warnings add `-Wall -Wextra` to your `gcc` or `clang` compile string. (add `-pedantic` for several additional warnings). For `clang`, instead you can use `-Weverything`. For **VS** (`cl.exe` on windoze), add `/Wall` (or `/W3` to limit some of the extraneous warnings). Read and understand each warning. They will identify any problems, and the exact line on which they occur. You can learn as much about coding by simply listening to what your compiler is telling you as you can from most tutorials.

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void clean_stdin ()
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int get_int_input (int *n)
{
    *n = 0;

    for (;;) {
        int rtn, tmp;

        printf ("Enter an integer: ");

        rtn = scanf ("%d", &tmp);

        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* handle user canceled input */
            fputs ("(user canceled input).\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        if (rtn == 1) {     /* good input, set *n = tmp, clean, return */
            *n = tmp;
            clean_stdin();
            return 0;
        }
        /* handle matching or input failure */
        fputs ("error: invalid input.\n", stderr);
        clean_stdin();
    }
}

int multible (int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf ("%d * %d = %d \n", n, i + 1, n * (i + 1));
    }
    return 0;
}

int main (void)
{
    int n;

    if (get_int_input (&n))
        return 1;

    multible (n);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compile with Warnings Enabled**

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -o bin/getintinput getintinput.c
```

**Example Use/Output**

Considering the cases of bad input and the user canceling:

```
$ ./bin/getintinput
Enter an integer: foo
error: invalid input.
Enter an integer: foo
error: invalid input.
Enter an integer: (user canceled input).
```

The valid input case:

```
$ ./bin/getintinput
Enter an integer: 12
12 * 1 = 12
12 * 2 = 24
12 * 3 = 36
12 * 4 = 48
12 * 5 = 60
12 * 6 = 72
12 * 7 = 84
12 * 8 = 96
12 * 9 = 108
12 * 10 = 120
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the strtol function. Do consider how to handle the errors. using it you can easly create the integer testing function